# jquery - how to change the selector keeping the action same

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have an array `Boxes={"#box5","#box3",#box1"","#box2","#box4"}` and I have a jquery statement

```
$(Boxes[2]).click(--------some code----------)
```

my problem is that the statement is always executed as - when box1 is clicked even though I swap the Box array several times in between. So even when `Boxes[2] = "box2"` the code is still executed when I click box1 and not box2.

Is this some sort of preprocessing?

Comment: Did you mean Boxes = { "#box5", "#box3", "#box1", "#box2", "#box4" }; ?

Comment: i think he meant an array `Boxes = ["#box5","#box3",#box1"","#box2","#box4"]`

Comment: See @ariel's answer for why it's not working the way you want it to. It can't literally work the way you want it to, but if you explain your broader problem (probably in a different question, as it changes the question markedly), I suspect we'll have some good suggestions for how to solve the broader problem.

Comment: @andreas: I hope he didn't, that's (still) a syntax error. ;-) @TheSuperTramp's probably got it.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `$(Boxes[2])` what matters is the value of `Boxes[2]` on the time you call it.

So the better is hook the click event to all boxes and inside the code check whether the array value is the box being clicked or not.

Sample:

```
// bind to all elements that id begin with "box"
$("id^=[box]").click(function() {
    // see if the clicked box is the one we want
    if ($(this).id == Boxes[2]) {
       // some code
    }
})
```

Comment: Exactly. What gets passed into the `$()` function is the *value* retrieved from `Boxes[2]`. There's no way for the `$()` function to know it came from an array vs. a literal vs. a string variable vs. an expression...